# TTTableSubtitleItem squishes image and does not clip it?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, three20

I am using a TTTableSubtitleItem with UITableViewStyleGrouped.  When viewing the tableView, the image that is in the TTTableSubtitleItem gets skewed to fit the image view (rather than just placing image without changing dimensions) and also the image does not get a rounded edge when it is the first item in the section.

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to fix these two issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to subclass TTTableSubtitleItem and draw my own images.